# Prevent Insert After from Repeating on Resize jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where the insert .after is repeating when the window is resized. I only want the insert .after to fire immediately one time when it's resized -- not repeatedly. What's a good solution to solve this problem?

```
if ($(options.accord) .length > 0) {
  if ($(window).width() < 470) {
    $tabs.addClass('example').after('enter tags here');
  }
  $(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window) .width() < 470) {
      $tabs.addClass('example').after('enter tags here');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: you want the whole code that you presented to be fired only once on resize?

Comment: i updated the code. i forgot to include the resize(). I just want the resize to load once when resized.

Comment: Why don't you just check for the `.example` class before doing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a local variable to notice whether the `after()` has been run or not. The inner function will still have access to the local variable when it runs:

```
if ($(options.accord) .length > 0) {
  var afterAdded = false;

  if ($(window).width() < 470) {
    $tabs.addClass('example').after('enter tags here');
    afterAdded = true;
  }

  $(window).resize(function () {
    if (($(window) .width() < 470) && ! afterAdded) {
      $tabs.addClass('example').after('enter tags here');
      afterAdded = true;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are removing the `example` class when the size is bigger and you have more code for each of the 2 conditions. You can check for the `example` class and then do your add/remove

```
if ($(options.accord) .length > 0) {
  if ($(window).width() < 470) {
    if( !$tabs.hasClass('example') ) {
        $tabs.addClass('example').after('enter tags here');
    }
  }
  $(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window) .width() < 470) {
      if( !$tabs.hasClass('example') ) {
          $tabs.addClass('example').after('enter tags here');
      }
    }
  });
}
```